# Why am I obtaining all these errors trying to implement a custom compoent that wrap the PrimeNG Schedule component?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-components

I am pretty new in **Angular 2\4** and in **PrimeNG**.

I am going crazy trying to replicate this tutorial related to the **Schedule** component of **PrimeNG**: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

If you click on the **Source** tab under the example it is shown the code of this example (I think that it is the code related this example...).

I am trying to create a custom **custom-schedule** component that wrap this schedule component provided by PrimeNG.

So I created a **custom-schedule** folder in my project.

Into this folder I put these files:

1) **custom-schedule.component.html** (the view), that simply contains this:

```
<p-schedule [events]="events"></p-schedule>
```

to schow the output of the PrimeNG schedule component.

2) **custom-schedule.component.ts** (the controller), that simply contains this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-schedule',
  templateUrl: './custom-schedule.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-schedule.component.css']
})
export class CustomScheduleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I also have the CSS file that is empty.

Then into the **app.component.html** file (the view of the main component of my project) I have:

```
<!--The whole content below can be removed with the new code.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
</div>

<app-custom-schedule></app-custom-schedule>
```

where I am calling my custom component using the PrimeNG schedule.

This is the **app.module.ts** file of my project:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CalendarModule, CheckboxModule, DialogModule, ScheduleModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CustomCalendarComponent } from './custom-calendar/custom-calendar.component';
import { CustomScheduleComponent } from './custom-schedule/custom-schedule.component';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {EventService} from "./custom-schedule/eventservice.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomCalendarComponent,
    CustomScheduleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CalendarModule,
    ScheduleModule,
    DialogModule,
    HttpModule,
    CheckboxModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The problem is that when I run my application I obtain these errors message into the browser console:

```
VM1164:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp../node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:6:170)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp../node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:6:178)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp../node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object../node_modules/script-loader/index.js!./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js (fullcalendar.min.js?c6f4:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54)
    at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:52)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:25)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ VM1164:6
(anonymous) @ VM1164:6
webpackJsonp../node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports @ addScript.js:9
./node_modules/script-loader/index.js!./node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js @ fullcalendar.min.js?c6f4:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
2 @ scripts.bundle.js:52
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:25
(anonymous) @ scripts.bundle.js:1
CustomScheduleComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function
    at Schedule.webpackJsonp../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.initialize (schedule.js:211)
    at Schedule.webpackJsonp../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.ngAfterViewChecked (schedule.js:193)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11185)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11157)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11141)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12244)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
View_CustomScheduleComponent_0 @ CustomScheduleComponent.html:1
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:14971
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:13398
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4814
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.es5.js:3844
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.tick @ core.es5.js:4814
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_._loadComponent @ core.es5.js:4782
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ core.es5.js:4770
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4546
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap @ core.es5.js:4546
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4508
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.es5.js:3890
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
(anonymous) @ zone.js:831
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:3881
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:191
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:235
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:829
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:918
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.es5.js:4537
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ core.es5.js:4522
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
3 @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:25
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
CustomScheduleComponent.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_CustomScheduleComponent_0 @ CustomScheduleComponent.html:1
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:14971
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:13398
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1085
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4814
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.es5.js:3844
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.tick @ core.es5.js:4814
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_._loadComponent @ core.es5.js:4782
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ core.es5.js:4770
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4546
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap @ core.es5.js:4546
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4508
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.es5.js:3890
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
(anonymous) @ zone.js:831
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:3881
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:191
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:235
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:829
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:918
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.es5.js:4537
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ core.es5.js:4522
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
3 @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:25
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
core.es5.js:2925 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
CustomScheduleComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function
    at Schedule.webpackJsonp../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.initialize (schedule.js:211)
    at Schedule.webpackJsonp../node_modules/primeng/components/schedule/schedule.js.Schedule.ngAfterViewChecked (schedule.js:193)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11185)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11157)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11141)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12244)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
View_CustomScheduleComponent_0 @ CustomScheduleComponent.html:1
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:14971
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:13398
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4814
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.es5.js:3844
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.tick @ core.es5.js:4814
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:4684
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.es5.js:3890
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:141
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.run @ core.es5.js:3821
next @ core.es5.js:4684
schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3635
webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3621
checkStable @ core.es5.js:3855
onHasTask @ core.es5.js:3903
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:444
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:464
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:288
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:208
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:235
webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:829
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:918
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.es5.js:4537
webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ core.es5.js:4522
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
3 @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 0ca06893c67582749f01:25
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
CustomScheduleComponent.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

So what could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it and obtain the schedule component into my view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install moment.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment